Filling gaps in weatherproof switch gland
I have an IP66 weatherproof switch unit like this with 20mm knockouts on all 4 sides:

And some glands like this:

For... reasons... I want to pass 3 cables though one gland. I can physically fit the cables through, but there are obviously large gaps between the cables that would allow water ingress.

This won't be a permanent outdoor installation - it'll be only used for a few hours at a time a couple of times a year, and stored away somewhere dry the rest of the time, but it needs to reliably cope with rain while it's being used on those occasions, and be able to pass UK PAT tests.
Is there something I can fill the gland with to make it weatherproof (e.g. would silicone sealant be appropriate)?
Or should I rethink the whole idea?
——-
Update
Inspired by @jasen and @mjt’s answers I’ve bought some solid rubber gland inserts that I’m planning on drilling custom holes into and replacing with the inserts that came with the glands I’ve already bought. If it works I’ll post it as another answer…

silicone sealant would work

As a quick and dirty solution, run all the wires through a single hole, put that hole at the bottom of the case,l (rotate the case if necessary), make sure the cables have drip loops, and caulk as best you can. Then make sure there is a GFCI upstream of this; built, suspenders, and skyhook

@jasen - that was a typo - should have been UK PAT Testing - link also added..

@keshlam: Yep. Note that "GFCI" is often referred to as "RCD" in the UK.

Typo: s/built/belt/. Someday I will learn to stop trusting the phone.

@keshlam :-). I’d already done that and s/suspenders/braces in my head. When you collect the skyhooks can you ask for a long weight as well…

The box has 4 knockouts, what about using 1 gland per knocknout? The routing will not be amazing, but as this is not permanent installation, it might not matter.


Glands have a rubber insert; you can get inserts with multiple holes, as pictured here. Obviously, you'll need to match the size of your cable, your rubber insert, and your gland.

Thanks - this got me thinking in the right direction. My cables are a tight squeeze in the gland, even getting them to pass though the hole in the outer plastic cap was a challenge. I’ve bought some solid inserts I’m going to try to make into the right shape, and fill with sealant where required…

Do it right: replace the one hole rubber insert in the cable gland with a three-hole one.
The first part of Portable appliance testing is a visual inspection so it has to look like it's done right.  After that comes electrical tests which will pass if you use good parts correctly.

It didn’t even occur to me there might be rubber insets with different profiles :-S. in my case the 3 cables are a pretty tight squeeze - the cables all touch inside with a tiny triangle in the middle. I’ve bought some solid insets that I’ll try to drill a custom shape out of and squirt some sealant into the tiny gap between the cables.

Another solution, if your drilling doesn't bear fruit.
In the past, I have 3D printed custom gland inserts out of TPU, to allow me to seal around twin & earth. If you have access to someone that has a 3D printer and some TPU, that might be an option.
If it comes to it, I'd be happy to print something for you!
